# sublistas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas, necesito ayuda con este enunciado:

"Modifica el programa anterior para que tenga en cuenta el género del destinatario, para eso, tendran que recibir una lista de listas, con nombre y género."

El programa anterior es el siguiente:

```
cont=0
lista=[]

nombre=""
while cont<=5:
    nombre=input("Escribe un nombre: ")
    lista.append(nombre)
    cont=cont+1

p=int(input("Escribe un posición: "))
n=int(input("Escribe una cantidad: "))

for nom in lista[p:n+1]:
    print ("Querido",nom ,"me alegro de verte")
```

Lo que hace estre programa es que te permite crear una lista con una serie de nombres que el usuario introduce, despues el usuario introduce la posicion de inicio de la lista y la cantidad de nombres que quiere ver al final. Ahora lo tengo que modificar par aque pueda hacer lo que me pide en el enunciaod de arriba.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cual es tu pregunta o problema?

Comment: La pregunta es: Como modifico el programa de arriba para que el usuario pueda introducir el sexo de cada nombre haciendo que sea una lista dentro de otra lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las listas es un tipo de dato que puede almacenar cualquier otro tipo de dato, tal como otra lista, en tu caso solo debes añadir `append([nombre, genero])`.

Python puede desempaquetar listas de forma muy sencilla, en tu caso podrias usar `for nom, gen in lista[p:n+1]:`

**Codigo:**

```
lista=[]

cont = 0
while cont<=5:
    nombre=input("Escribe un nombre: ")
    genero=input("Indique su genero: ")
    lista.append([nombre, genero])
    cont += 1

p=int(input("Escribe un posición: "))
n=int(input("Escribe una cantidad: "))

for nom, gen in lista[p:n+1]:
    print ("Querido",nom ,"me alegro de verte, tu genero es ", gen)
```

*Nota:* En python no es necesario declarar las variables por lo que la intrucción de `nombre=""` antes del while es innecesario.

Comment: Okey, gracias por la  ayuda, me ha sido muy util.

Comment: @Alex Cuando una respuesta es util se acostumbra a marcarla como correcta, si no sabe como hacerlo revise el siguiente link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour